# chat with particular online user in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

i want chat with particular online user like facebook or gmail..using node.js and socket.io please help me..thanks advance..

**Client.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>my chat app</title>
<div id="login">
<form id="chat_msg">
<label>Enter Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username"/>
<input type="button" id="join" value="Create Username"/>
</form>
</div>
<div>
<div id="online_users"><li>List of online users:</li></div>
</div>
<!---public room chat begins here----->
<div id="chat" style="display: none;">
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
      <input id="msg" autocomplete="off" />
     <button id="send" >Send</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <!---private chat begins here----->
    <div id="private_chat" style="display: none;">
    <p id="private_user">Private chat with: </p>
    <div id="private_msg"></div>
    <form>
     <input id="p_msg" autocomplete="off" />
      <button id="p_send" >Send private msg</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var username = null;
      var socket = io();
     $('#chat').hide();
$('#username').focus();
      $('form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});


    $('#join').click(function(){
        username = $('#username').val();
       console.log('entered username '+username);
       if(username !=''){
        socket.emit('new_user', username);
        $('#login').detach();
        $('#chat').show();
        $('#msg').focus();
       }
    });

    $('#send').click(function(){
         socket.emit('send_msg', $('#msg').val());
    $('#msg').val('');

    });


  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      //$('#messages').append('<b>'+ username + ':</b> ' + msg + '<br>');
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });

  socket.on('update_personal', function(status){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(status));
  });

  socket.on('update_users', function(names){
    console.log(names);


    if(true) {

                          $("#online_users").empty();
            $.each(names, function(clientid, name) {
                $('#online_users').append("<li><a href='#' id='"+name+"' name='"+name+"' class='private'> " + name + "</a></li>");

            });


     $('a.private').click(function(){
  $('#private_chat').hide();

  $('#private_chat').show();
  var sender = username;


var recipient = $(this).attr('name');


  console.log('name gotten is:'+recipient);
  $('p#private_user').html('private chat with :'+ recipient);

    $('#p_send').click(function(){
        msg = $('#p_msg').val();
        if(msg!=''){
            recipient=recipient;
         socket.emit('private_msg', msg,recipient,sender); // msg from sender, username of the sender, username of recipient
   $('#p_msg').val('');
   }
   else{
    $('#p_msg').val('please enter a valid msg');

    }
    });
  });


                }
  });
  socket.on('received_p_msg', function(msg,sender,recipient){
     $('#private_chat').show();

     console.log('received privatemsg: '+msg);
     $('#private_user').html('privat chat with : '+ sender);
    $('#private_msg').append($('<div>').html(msg+'</div>'));

    //to continue chat after receiving initial private msg
    $('#p_send').click(function(){
        msg = $('#p_msg').val();
           if(msg!=''){
         socket.emit('private_msg', msg,sender,recipient); // msg from sender, username of the sender, username of recipient
    $('#p_msg').val('');
   }else{$('#p_msg').val('please enter a valid msg');
   }

    $('#p_msg').val('');

    });

   });

  socket.on("disconnect", function(){
        $("#msgs").append("The server is not available");

  });

</script>
```

**server.js**

```
  var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),

    sio = require('socket.io');

var usernames={};
var sockets = {};
var names= {};


var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(fs.readFileSync('./index.html'));
});
server.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('Server listening');
});
io = sio.listen(server)
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('send_msg', function(msg){
     console.log('a user connected');
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
    //console.log(msg);

  });

   socket.on('new_user',function(user){
    console.log('new user:'+user);
       names[socket.id] = user;
       socket.nickname= user;
       usernames[socket.nickname] = socket;
        sockets[user]=socket.id;
        socket.emit('update_personal', "you are now online");
        io.emit('update_users',names);

    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){

        io.emit('update_personal', socket.nickname+' is now offline');
         delete names[socket.id];
         delete usernames[socket.nickname];
            io.emit('update_users',names);
          //console.log(usernames+'specific user id'+usernames[user]);
    });

    socket.on('private_msg', function(msg,recipient,sender){

        console.log('you are trying to send '+msg+' to '+recipient+ ' from '+sender);


        var id = sockets[recipient];

        console.log(sockets[recipient]);
      io.to(id).emit('received_p_msg', msg,sender,recipient);

      recipient = '';
      console.log('value in recipient:'+recipient);


    });
});
```

this code working perfect but private chat not working correctly when i click online user opening only one text box for private chat i want to open multiple chat box like facebook or gmail..

Comment: What issues you are facing? What errors you getting? Just your code is not enough so please share all things you are facing.

Comment: 'Please Help Me' is not a specific issue. What is the problem.

Comment: Please describe why you think this isn't working. Try to refer to specific lines of the code.

Comment: i already tried but it not working..

Answer (score 0):

The idea to send message to specific user amend the code on Client side 
This will help you to send user private message

```
$('#send').click(function(){
  var recieverName = ''// ANY unique name or userId 
   socket.emit(recieverName, $('#msg').val());
   $('#msg').val('');
});

//// username is connected user unique name or userId (will get on #join click)
socket.on(username, function(msg){
  //$('#messages').append('<b>'+ username + ':</b> ' + msg + '<br>');
  $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
});
```

Comment: this code sending message particular only one user ..after clicking different user for sending message not working..like gmail

Comment: yes you have to optimize it like click on any user , userID or name will be place on recieverName, and Emit the message

Comment: can you please edit and send full code...i tried i am not getting correctly .